# minimalistic mongodb to query tx | config.ini

Tags: nodeos, transactions, storage, node

I setup a non-producing node and an API to let an app query user transactions. API is similar to the [CryptoLions/EOS-mongo-history-API](https://github.com/CryptoLions/EOS-mongo-history-API)

What is the most minimalistic and effective approach to decrease sync time and storage? So far I use the following. Problem now is that when I query a tx, its returned 3 times from the mongodb, so I guess I can remove 2 of 3 mongodb-store-... options

```
agent-name = apibackend

http-server-address = 0.0.0.0:8888
p2p-listen-endpoint = 0.0.0.0:9876

blocks-dir = "/mnt/xfs/mainnet/blocks" 

bnet-endpoint = 0.0.0.0:4321
bnet-follow-irreversible = 0
bnet-no-trx = false
read-mode = read-only
validation-mode = light
mongodb-uri = mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/EOS
mongodb-queue-size = 2048
mongodb-abi-cache-size = 2048
mongodb-block-start = 1
mongodb-store-transactions = 1
mongodb-store-transaction-traces = 1           <------ needed?
mongodb-store-action-traces = 1                <------ needed?
mongodb-filter-on = *
mongodb-filter-out = eosio:onblock:
mongodb-filter-out = gu2tembqgage::
mongodb-filter-out = blocktwitter::

wasm-runtime = wabt
p2p-max-nodes-per-host = 1
http-validate-host = false
https-client-validate-peers = 1
abi-serializer-max-time-ms = 5000
chain-state-db-size-mb = 32000
reversible-blocks-db-size-mb = 340
contracts-console = false
allowed-connection = any
max-clients = 100
network-version-match = 0
sync-fetch-span = 500
connection-cleanup-period = 30
max-implicit-request = 1500
access-control-allow-origin = *
access-control-allow-headers = *
access-control-allow-credentials = false
verbose-http-errors = true

plugin = eosio::chain_plugin
plugin = eosio::chain_api_plugin              <------ needed?
plugin = eosio::bnet_plugin
plugin = eosio::mongo_db_plugin
plugin = eosio::http_plugin                   <------ needed?
```

Will `--mongodb-filter-on=*` interfere with `mongodb-store-transactions = 1` or is it even obsolete ? Download all actions from anyone VS download all tx from anyone.  Not sure if this works but it could be a solution: `--mongodb-filter-on=*:transfer:` -->

> Track actions which match
>                                           receiver:action:actor. Actor may be blank
>                                           to include all. Receiver and Action may
>                                           not be blank. Default is * include
>                                           everything.

Comment: Btw, if you want to minimalize your mongo storage, also consider to filter out all spammer actions. https://github.com/eosbean/eos-spammer-list

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Heifner (Contributor) replied on [Github here](https://github.com/EOSIO/eos/issues/6002):

---

- `abi-serializer-max-time-ms = 5000` needs to be larger or you will have problems with action data not being serialized and remaining in hex.
- What you store depends on what kind of queries you want to support.

-

```
# Enables storing blocks in mongodb. (eosio::mongo_db_plugin)
mongodb-store-blocks = 1  

# Enables storing block state in mongodb. (eosio::mongo_db_plugin)  
mongodb-store-block-states = 1  

# Enables storing transactions in mongodb. (eosio::mongo_db_plugin)  
mongodb-store-transactions = 1  

# Enables storing transaction traces in mongodb. (eosio::mongo_db_plugin)  
mongodb-store-transaction-traces = 1  

# Enables storing action traces in mongodb. (eosio::mongo_db_plugin)  
mongodb-store-action-traces = 1
```

The default on all the -store- options is true (1), so you have to explilcitly disable if not interested in storing a particular collection.

`mongodb-store-blocks`

- Stores complete signed blocks
- No filtering is applied

`mongodb-store-block-states`

- Stores the block states which is some meta data about the block
- No filtering is applied

`mongodb-store-transactions`

- Stores incoming transactions
- Filtering is applied as of 1.4 release

`mongodb-store-transaction-traces`

- Stores the transaction trace (result) including all the action traces
- Filtering is applied

`mongodb-store-action-traces`

- Stores the action trace (result) of the transaction trace seperately
- Filtering is applied